# infinite loop in Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

In my facebook app, I get an infinite redirect loop because of the following two lines, although it was working yesterday!

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => $fbconfig['appUrl'], 'scope' => 'user_birthday,email'));
  print "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

Apparently the problem is in getting user data from API:

```
if ($user) {
      try {
        // If the user has been authenticated then proceed
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
}
```

Comment: check the content of `$loginUrl` Its may be not what you are expecting for some reason

Comment: nothing wrong, it is the same I need

Comment: is it the right protocol? (http vs https?) this just burned me bad, i spent 2 hours working on it.